# ProLoser AnythingSlider problems with main background image in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, css, anythingslider

Here's my page:
http://www.hairextensiongeek.com/videos.php?vid=1

AnythingSlider is working great in all browsers except IE7 - surprise surprise. For some odd reason the background image of the entire page is offset a variable amount of pixels depending on the browser size. I've narrowed down the problem to the left and right navigation since when I disable navigation in the jquery the problem goes away. The metallic-styling CSS is using negative background values to hide the various buttons (perhaps I just answered my own question :)

Just need the IE fix to the background positioning. (I may try independent images that don't require negative background values.)

Also I know IE7 is nearly out of date but I use it to get the full range of potential problems ;)

Thanks in advance
nicholas

p.s. Trying to use multiple images versus negative background positions didn't help. It must be the actual arrow div container causing the issue I imagine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is with the negative top margin being used to center the arrow images vertically.

Try changing the top from 50% to whatever percentage centers the image for you, then just set the magin of the link to zero, like this:

```
/* Navigation Arrows */
div.anythingSlider-metallic .arrow {
  top: 30%; /* adjust this percentage to vertically center your arrows */
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  z-index: 100;
}
div.anythingSlider-metallic .arrow a {
  display: block;
  height: 95px;
  /* margin-top: -47px; - half height of image - REMOVE THIS LINE */
  margin: 0;
  width: 45px;
  outline: 0;
  background: url(../images/arrows-metallic.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Also, remove the `text-indent: -9999px` because that is also messing up the positioning.

---

**Update:** [Version 1.5.10](http://proloser.github.com/AnythingSlider/), which was released today, includes a separate stylesheet for IE7 with these changes.

Comment: hey, that fixed it! Thanks a bunch. I had completely given up on it and just turned off the arrows all together. Awesome!